# old file co-exist (without slash after docRoot) with new file

Tags: php, html, css, http, url

Codeigniter controller accessing css at below mentioned location is getting the old css

Updated file (note the // after example.com):
http://www.example.com//assets/css/abc.css

Old file (note the / after example.com):
http://www.example.com/assets/css/abc.css

Comment: press `ctrl-shift-R`

Comment: the problem is the codeigniter controller calling css at base_url()/assets/css/abc.css is getting the old file